What is the "extended private masterkey" line of a dumpwallet file?
What is the "extended private masterkey" in a dumpwallet file? It begins with xprv.

I found this helpful: https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/keys/hd-wallets/extended-keys/

It is the BIP32 extended private key which all wallet keys are indirectly derived from. Anyone with access to it can compute all the wallet's private keys.

"Anyone with access to it" (plus a private key, for hardened derivation, right?) "can compute all the wallet's private keys."

Extended private keys let you compute all private keys; there is no other information needed. The extended private key is literally where the keys come from.

What is hardened vs. non-hardened derivation?

With normal (non-hardened) derivation you can get the public keys from the extended public key, as well as the corresponding private keys from the corresponding extended private key. With hardened derivation, there is no usable extended public key, and one needed the extended private key to derive both private and public keys. Hardened is more secure in certain scenarios, but is not as feature-rich.
